# Get type of wincontrol - c#

Tags: c#, windows, api, winapi, handle

I need to get the type of a wincontrol in a window using the mouse icon position.
Now I can identify the class but not the type. How can I get it?

[image]

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoint, int yPoint);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

private void test()
{
Point pt = MousePosition;
IntPtr w = WindowFromPoint(pt.X, pt.Y);

MessageBox.Show(GetWinClass(w));


}

public static string GetWinClass(IntPtr hwnd)
{
if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
return null;
StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(100);
IntPtr result = GetClassName(hwnd, classname, classname.Capacity);
if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
return classname.ToString();
return null;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That Notepad menu would have been created via the CreateMenu() API, its not a control, has no associated type and is not even a window with an HWND.

Comment: You are lacking quite a bit of understanding of Win32, which is going to be a hindrance. What is the underlying problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm looking for a mode to manipulate the menus and others controls in a window. I can do it using the coordinate position in a especific window, but there are another mode? Can I Iterating in objects of a window and compare properties to find the looked object?

Comment: This is the classic XY problem, as I suspected. You are asking about your imagined solution, but it's the wrong solution. We could attempt to answer the question you asked, but it won't help you because you've selected the wrong solution to your problem. You are looking for UI Automation.

Comment: In fact, you are already using terminology well-suited for UI Automation, so you should find using it directly to be much easier. In C#, this is done with the System.Windows.Automation namespace, but I forget if there was a third party binding that was better (and also what made it better).

Comment: @andlabs Although I have not been very clear but really the System.Windows.Automation can help me a lot. I did not know this namespace. This is new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no well-defined idea of a "window type" in Windows. As you found, you can get a HWND from a specific point and then retrieve the class name from there. However, that is about all that you can do reliably. Any decisions of the window type based on the class name are purely speculative and usually rely on mapping well-known class names to arbitrary type definitions.

One place to start is MSDN documentation such as this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx. However again, that doesn't cover a lot of custom applications that are written using third-party IDEs (e.g. Delphi has popup combo boxes with classname 'TwwPopupGrid').

Answer (score -1):

A `MenuItem` is an instance of a class from the `WinForms` technology.

Windows does not know which class has been used to put text on the screen, in fact it does not know which technology has been used (`WinForms`, `WPF`, `MFC`, ...) so you cannot know the type (class) of the visual element under the cursor.

You can probably create visual elements with just a `main()` method and putting inside all the methods required so which type would you have then?

Comment: In the Windows API a "window class" is a template from which windows can be created. It has nothing to do with WinForms or MFC. What you said is still true for WinForms and MFC, but it does not answer the question here. Notepad does not use any special technologies. Furthermore, Windows does provide a whole host of menu APIs for building menus; this is not somehting that is left up to the application developer (unless they want to build *everything* from scratch). This question is talking about pure Windows API (given the APIs used in the code snippet).